# C# how to avoid files that need authorization?

Tags: c#, file, exception

OK guys, i got the next problem

I have to go on a specific drive, in mine case its A (just made it for testing, bc it is small (6 folders and a few more files))

On that drive, i have to get a list of all folders and subfolders and files and write it down to an XML file....

now i am almost done...

i have all the folders and files in an DirectoryInfo

and when i go in a foreach loop through the files, i get to one witch need authorization from the OS and that throws an exception, and the program fails...

Now i need to handle that exception, just to skip that file, and go to the next...

Can u help me?

Here's the code:

```
private static XElement GetDirectoryXml(DirectoryInfo dir)
    {
        var info = new XElement("dir", new XAttribute("name", dir.Name));


        foreach (var file in dir.GetFiles()) //here is the exception
        {
            info.Add(new XElement("file", new XAttribute("name", file.Name)));
        }

        foreach (var subDir in dir.GetDirectories())
        {
            info.Add(GetDirectoryXml(subDir));
        }

        return info;
    }
```

The exception is this:An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Access to the path 'A:\Config.Msi' is denied.

i tried a try catch block

```
 foreach (var file in dir.GetFiles())
        {
            try
            {
                info.Add(new XElement("file", new XAttribute("name", file.Name)));
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                continue;
            }
            finally
            { }
        }
```

and it was the same result

BTW here is the whole code, i am usinf MS Visual Studio 2013

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var doc = new XDocument();
        var driver = new DriveInfo(@"A:\");
        foreach (var dir in driver.RootDirectory.GetDirectories())
        {
            doc = new XDocument(GetDirectoryXml(dir));

        }
        Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
        Console.Read();
    }

    private static XElement GetDirectoryXml(DirectoryInfo dir)
    {
        var info = new XElement("dir", new XAttribute("name", dir.Name));


        foreach (var file in dir.GetFiles())
        {
            try
            {
                info.Add(new XElement("file", new XAttribute("name",
                    file.Name)));
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                continue;
            }
            finally
            { }
        }
        foreach (var subDir in dir.GetDirectories())
        {
            info.Add(GetDirectoryXml(subDir));
        }

        return info;
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: So....it seems you know the right words "handle an exception". Did you try doing a web search to see how you handle exceptions in C#?

Comment: i tried this: try
            {
                foreach (var file in dir.GetFiles())
                {
                    info.Add(new XElement("file", new XAttribute("name", file.Name)));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
            finally
            { } but it didnt work

Comment: You said you tried something, you didn't say if it did what you wanted it to or not.

Comment: Post what you tried, what happened and what you wanted/expected to happen.

Comment: i posted it at the bot....the try catch block....but its again the same error at the same place....at the foreach line

Comment: Yes, because you need to wrap that inside the try block as well. It isn't `info.Add(...)` that is throwing the exception, it is `dir.GetFiles()`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't inside the loop, but rather the calls to `dir.GetDirectories` or `dir.GetFiles`. You need the `try` / `catch` to encompass them:

```
private static XElement GetDirectoryXml(DirectoryInfo dir)
{
    var info = new XElement("dir", new XAttribute("name", dir.Name));

    try
    {
        foreach (var file in dir.GetFiles()) //here is the exception
        {
            info.Add(new XElement("file", new XAttribute("name", file.Name)));
        }

        foreach (var subDir in dir.GetDirectories())
        {
            info.Add(GetDirectoryXml(subDir));
        }
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
    {
    }
    return info;
}
```

Comment: yyyy, i want to skip it, how to do it?

Comment: @bro1: See my update. I think that'll do what you're asking for.

Comment: @bro1: That's good to hear. If this solved your problem, please remember to mark it as the accepted answer.